# Apple Calendar App - meeting not showing up

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mail.app

I have a meeting that's not showing up on my Apple Calendar but is showing up on the calendar on my Microsoft Teams app. I verified that calendars are enabled for my Exchange account under **System Settings** > **Internet Accounts**. What could it be?

PS. I'm on Ventura.